# Java top level enums - super type

Tags: java, enums

I have the following enums in a J2ee application,
They represent the saved documents for student or teacher in the DB

```
public enum  StudentDocumentTypeEnum     
           Student Card
           Cafeteria benefit Card               

public enum  TeacherDocumentTypeEnum
           Employee Card
           Benefits Card
           Parking access Card
```

Currently in the back-end both documents are saved to different tables,

```
saveDocument(byteArry[], TeacherDocumentTypeEnum)
saveDocument(byteArry[], StudentDocumentTypeEnum)
```

I would like to consolidate and create a single module that will save documents from both student or teacher

One solution is to create a method to save the document that will get consolidated "DocumentTypeEnum"

```
saveDocument(byteArry[], DocumentTypeEnum )
```

But I still want to be able to distinguish student or teacher type document enums, 
What is the best approach here?

- consolidating both enums
- converting the enums to classes hierarchy

any other suggestions?

Comment: What is this syntax for enum declaration ???

Comment: why do you want to consolidate them at the same time keep distinction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not having any code depending on the value of an objects property. This violates the *tell, don't ask!* principle.

Having written this I' suggest to create a `DocumentType` *interface*.

```
interface DocumentType{} // empty, just a tag

public enum  StudentDocumentTypeEnum  implements    DocumentType{
  // ..

public enum  TeacherDocumentTypeEnum  implements    DocumentType{
  // ..
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for all the changes--rethought it as I was writing it!

### Option 1 -- Interface

You could create a "CardHolder" interface with a single "Card[] getCards()" method that they both implement. It would be different for the two classes but would always return a list of documents to save.

```
public enum  StudentDocumentTypeEnum implements CardHolder
    Card student;
    Card cafeteriaBenefit;
    public Card[] getCards() {// Method on CardHolder
        return new Card[]{student, cafetriaBenifit};
    }

public enum TeacherDocumentTypeEnum implements CardHolder
       Card employee;
       Card benefits;
       Card parkingAccess;
       public Card[] getCards() {// Method on CardHolder
          return new Card[]{employee, benefits, parkingAccess};
       }
```

### Option 2 -- Reflective

An other option is to accept an "Enum" and access it reflectively, that way you could still keep your existing structure.  Just remember that reflection has a lot of drawbacks--it's not obvious code, it can't be "refactored" with tooling it is unproven at compile time (how do you tell the coder to only pass in a student or teacher when the method signature says it takes any "Enum"?)

### Option 3 -- Refactor

Finally this may not be a case for enums at all.  Why not have Student and Teacher objects, each with a collection of cards that extend the same base-class or implement the same interface?

Comment: Thank you, seems like getCards seems redundant any code change will need to be double...

Comment: Any change?  It's a single line of code to implement and unlikely you'll need to revisit it unless you change the number of Cards in the enum  It's a reasonable workaround to a fairly annoying problem (lack of enum inheritance.)